# Insert New UITableViewCell in Master from Detail

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, master-detail

I have a simple master-detail application and I'm using the detail view to configure data to insert into the master list.

I have a custom class called "Calculation," which is the object I need to insert into each row.

I can pass the object from the detail view to the master view just fine, it just won't insert a new row.

In the detail view I Initiate my object, populate it with data and send it to the "insertNewObject" method in the MasterViewController using a custom segue:

```
- (IBAction)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *s = @"1";
    NSNumber *n = [f numberFromString:s];

    Calculation *calc = [[Calculation alloc] initWithValue:@"$1661.70" descr:@"1 Ounce 24k Gold" textInput:@"1" percentDisplay:@"0%" purityIndex:n metalIndex:n weightUnitIndex:n sliderValue:n];

    [segue.destinationViewController insertNewObject:calc];
}
```

And in the MasterViewController, here is my insert code:

```
    -(void)insertNewObject:(NSObject *)newCalculation {

        if (!_objects) {
            _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [_objects insertObject:newCalculation atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSObject *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"value"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"descr"];
    cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    return cell;
}
```

I can print the object all day with NSLog in the MVC, but not matter how many times I add an object from the detail view controller, the array count is always 1, and no cell ever gets added to the tableview.

The same exact code works fine if I instantiate the object in MVC, and insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A segue is really the wrong mechanism for sending data from detail to master.  (It works great the other direction!)  You'd be better off defining a delegate protocol that has `-(void)insertNewObject:(NSObject *)newCalculation;` as a required method, making your master implement that protocol, and passing **it** as a delegate to your detail controller.

Then the detail controller just calls `[delegate insertNewObject:calc];`.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, can you give me a little more guidance on how exactly to implement the delegate/protocol?

Comment: If you're not familiar with protocols, the easier way (though not as 'elegant') is to put a property called delegate in your detail controller that holds a reference to your master controller.  In your original segue to the detail, have the master do something like `detail.delegate = self;`.  Import the master's .h file into detail's .m and then call the method as above.

Comment: Thanks again Phillip. I'm reading up on delegates and I'll mark your answer when I get it working. Having trouble at the moment.